# Find type from Assembly that implements particular interface

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection

am try implement plugin system for my application. The idea is that in a folder stores Users assembly. When my application starts i want get object list from users assemblies.

```
public void InitPlugins()
{
 var userAssemblies = Directory.GetFiles(PATH,"*.dll");
 foreach(var file in userAssemblies)
 {
   Assembly customAssembly = Assembly.Load(file);
   //How can I find all object implements IPlugin in this assembly?       
 }

}
```

Comment: I assume you've checked `Assembly` class for interesting methods like [GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx) ...  Is your question how to check if given class implements an interface? Side note: strictly speaking assemblies contain types/classes not objects.

Comment: Side note: I've edited title to match accepted question. Feel free to edit/revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work.

```
   foreach (Type type in customAssembly )
    {
       if (type.GetInterface("IPlugin") == typeof(IPlugin))
       {
         IPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPlugin;                      
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. Also I'd personally use `GetInterfaces` and check for matching type  with `Where` as it would be easier to deal with generic and duplicate interface names.